# Like an object from anbdroid app does not appear on facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have facebook object id = 235563339900978
(you can check it here - http://graph.facebook.com/235563339900978)

i have such code

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("object", "http://samples.ogp.me/235563339900978");

// DO PUBLISH
Request request = new Request(
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        "me/og.likes",
        params,
        HttpMethod.POST
);

return request.executeAndWait();
```

I run this code and get positive answer from facebook
response with code 200.
Also if I then again run that code i get such answer

```
errorMessage: (#3501) User is already associated to the object type, website, on a unique action type Like. Original Action ID: 1400818803525892}
```

so I suppose like was succesfull.
But i can not see it on timeline at all.
I did like, but it was not appear on timeline, 
despite the fact I saw positive response
with code 200.

Why?